# how to get the data value of the registry value inside a key using powershell

Tags: powershell

In my function I would like to search for a specific string in the data part of a particular subkey. Part of a code inside function follows:

```
 foreach ($CurrentPath in $Path) { 
    $Items = Get-Item -Path Registry::$CurrentPath
    ForEach ( $Property in $Items) {
      $Key = $Property
```

When I debug straight after `$Key = $Property` and go to the host command window and type `$Key` and press enter. It returns with:

```
Hive: hkcu

Name                           Property
----                           --------
ABC                            Test : ababab\MSSQLSERVER_2014\ababab
```

I would like my function to also search the data part as shown in the image attached which is in regedit.

[image: Regedit image sample]

How do I accomplish the search?

Comment: I think you need to look at using `get-itemproperty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the value-name you need to loop the properties. Example using  `Get-Item`:

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\NuGet"

foreach ($prop in $item.Property) {
    if($item.GetValue($prop) -match '0') { "Match found in key $($item.PSPath) , value $($prop)" }
}
```

Or `Get-ItemProperty`:

```
$item = Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\NuGet"

foreach ($prop in $item.psobject.Properties) {
    if($prop.Value -match '0') { "Match found in key $($item.PSPath) , value $($prop.Name)" }   
}
```

If you know the value-name, then it's easier to use `Get-ItemProperty` and `Where-Object`, ex:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\NuGet" | Where-Object { $_.IncludePrerelease -match '0' }
```

Comment: Thank you Frode F. Will take a look later in the afternoon or tomorrow. Something else came up..